# SQL Server 2005 adding total number in the bottom row of same productid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to know how to query a database where I can return Total in the bottom row.
One supplier has 8 Qty of WS-C3850-48P-S and other have 2 WS-C3850-48P-S
so the result should display 10

```
select [companyid]
  ,[productid]
  ,[productdescription],
   sum([Qty in Stock]) as TotalQty
from tblstock
where [productid] like '%WS-C3850-48P-S%'
group by ([Qty in Stock]),[companyid]
  ,[productid]
  ,[productdescription]

having ([Qty in Stock]) >0
order by [Qty in Stock] desc
```

I would like to see the result like this.

```
companyid  productid        productdescription        TotalQty
2          WS-C3850-48P-S   Cisco Catalyst 3850 48       2
3          WS-C3850-48P-S   Cisco Catalyst 3850 48       8
                                    Total                10
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct tblcompany.companyid,companyname,productid,
[Qty in Stock], StockDate
FROM tblstock 
join tblcompany
on tblstock.companyid = tblcompany.companyid
where [productid] like '%WS-C3850-48P-S%'
group by tblcompany.companyid,companyname,productid,[Qty in Stock],StockDate
having [Qty in Stock] > 0
order by StockDate desc
select sum([Qty in Stock]) as [Total Qty] from tblstock where [productid] like '%WS-C3850-48P-S%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WITH ROLLUP:

```
select [companyid]
  ,[productid]
  ,[productdescription],
   sum([Qty in Stock]) as TotalQty
from tblstock
where [productid] like '%WS-C3850-48P-S%'
group by ([Qty in Stock]),[companyid]
  ,[productid]
  ,[productdescription] WITH ROLLUP
having ([Qty in Stock]) >0
order by [Qty in Stock] desc
```

Comment: Thanks but its not the result I wanted to see. Check edited result table.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `GROUPING SETS` in `SQL SERVER`.

**Query**

```
select [companyid]
,[productid]
,[productdescription],
sum([Qty in Stock]) as TotalQty
from tblstock
where [productid] like '%WS-C3850-48P-S%'
group by GROUPING SETS((([Qty in Stock]),[companyid]
,[productid]
,[productdescription]),())
having ([Qty in Stock]) >0
order by [Qty in Stock] desc
```

Comment: I get an error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'SETS'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'Qty in Stock'.